# I am testing ArrayBuffer and wonder why the result looks like this:

Tags: javascript, memory, arraybuffer

Hi I am a beginner programmer who is studying JavaScript. When I look at the source, I create a view with a DataView (buffer) and put the value into position 0 with setUint32. Why does not the value 536870912 change to 32 when I load the buffer again with Uint32Array?

```
var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(76);
var view = new DataView(buffer);

var value = 20000000;

// set value 536807912
view.setUint32(0, parseInt(value, 16));

// [17/05/2019 10:00:20.149] [LOG]    getUint32 536870912
console.log('getUint32 ' + view.getUint32(0));

var test = new Uint32Array(buffer);

/* [17/05/2019 10:00:20.150] [LOG]    Uint32Array [ 32, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ] */
console.log(test);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you see 32 using `Uint32Array` is due to [Endianness](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Endianness). When using a `DataView`, the `setUint32` and `getUint32` functions have an additional parameter `littleEndian` and when left out it defaults to big-endian. Then, using a `Uint32Array`, it will use your system's endianness which in this case is little-endian.

So in the `Uint32Array` case you are setting the value using big-endian, then retrieving it using little-endian resulting in the value of 32.

To illustrate this, here are the two values using the different byte orders:

```
536870912 =
Little-endian:  00 00 00 20
Big-endian: 20 00 00 00

32 =
Little-endian:  20 00 00 00
Big-endian: 00 00 00 20
```